# Is there a way to keep fragile models together?

Tags: building, glue

My late husband built a number of Lego models that I would love to keep together. However having a 5 and 2 year old around this is proving difficult and parts keep getting knocked off. Is there any kind of spray glue type thing that I can use to hold the models together so they can stand up to curious little fingers. I know this not the best idea however I do not want them to end up in smithereens as I know they will never be remade again. I want to preserve the work my husband put into them.

Comment: One technique that I've used to record how my own models were built is to put a camera on a stand, aimed at the model, and dismantle the model, taking a photograph as each part is removed. It's often possible to rebuild the model from the parts you remove as you go, but if not, the photographs can be used as a guide. With suitable software you can even combine the photos into a film - in reverse order, so it shows the model being built.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for your loss.

I would hide them behind a locked glass door; even if you glue them, they won't likely survive a 2-year-old knocking them to the floor.

There is a product called [Le-Glue](https://www.amazon.ca/Glue-Temporary-LEGO%C2%AE-Blocks-Non-Toxic/dp/B00TFRSTCK) (amazon link) which I've never used which bills itself as temporary glue (you can dissolve it with water).

And, of course, there's always the [image: kragle].